# Serialize dynamically created form // Post ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some dynamically created content which includes a little form (dropdown with button) to assign someone to a task.

Using jquery, I want to update my database with the newly assigned person. My approach:

```
$('#messageDetail').on('click', '#assignButton', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin_assginMessage.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $("#assignForm").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
});
```

It seems it doesn't send me the form input. I have the feeling that I need to use .on() here, too, but I don't know **which event** I should choose:

```
    data: $("#assignForm").serialize(),
```

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: have you tried using **FormData()** variable ? Also see the error by doing the following ```error: function(error){console.log(error);}```

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying "**I created a form as a dynamically, but when I trying to serialize it, I can't see anything about dynamic form's data**", the solution is here:

```js
const dynamicForm = `
 <form id="frmData" onsubmit="return false">
 <label>Username
 <input type='text' name='username' />
 </label>

 <label>Password
 <input type='password' name='password' />
 </label>
 <button id="clickSend">Click and Send</button>
 </form>
`;

$("#addForm").on("click", () => {
 $("#frmarea").append(dynamicForm);
})

/* Send Form Details with Dynamic Form */

$(document).on("click", "#clickSend", () => {
 let serializeData = $("#frmData").serialize()
 
 console.log(serializeData)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frmarea"></div>

<button id="addForm">Add Form</button>
```

So you should use `$(document)` when you work with dynamic generated forms.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `event.preventDefault()` More here : [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
<script>
$("#assignForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "admin_assginMessage.php",
        type: "post",
        data: $("#assignForm").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning post data to a variable

```
$('#messageDetail').on('click', '#assignButton', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "admin_assginMessage.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {'mydata' : $("#assignForm").serialize()},
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
});
```